# Problem aligning an icon in center of Cell in AG Grid

Tags: css, angular, ag-grid

I am running into an issue when I try to align my checkmarks in the cells of my AG Grid. By default they are all left aligned but i would like them to be center aligned. I dont have a problem setting the alignment for text but for those material icons i have no luck.
Part of the problem seems to be also that span that holds the image might have the alignment set to center but that does not effect the column itself

[image]

Here is what the code for the cell looks like

```
<span class="ag-cell-value" role="presentation" id="cell-112"><span>
<span class="table-row-icon" style="align-items: center;">
    <i class="material-icons md-18" style="color: #ff6358;
        align-items:center;text-align:center;">done</i>
</span></span></span>
```

Comment: with material components sometimes you need to enforce your css rule to penetrate the default encapsulated styles. to do so you may need to add a deprecated, yet functional, feature which is                  ::ng-deep .your-css-class{text-align:  center !important}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem actually was that I need it to make display Flex. Applying the below style created the desired result.

{display: flex; justify-content center}

[image]